# What does "#if ..." (with an ellipsis) do?

Tags: c, windows, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I was doing some studying of the windows header files and I came upon a preprocessor statement that I didn't recognize. I've been searching for any information on this statement for about a week and I can't find any information on it anywhere. I'm not sure if it's just not a search engine friendly phrase or if there really isn't much on the web about it. I've found a couple uses of this preprocessor in the MS header files.

Here is an example from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-sid) page:

```
typedef struct _SID {
    BYTE Revision;
    BYTE SubAuthorityCount;
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY IdentifierAuthority;
    #if ...
        DWORD * SubAuthority[];
    #else
        DWORD SubAuthority[ANYSIZE_ARRAY];
    #endif
} SID, *PSID;
```

Note: I'm asking specifically about `#if ...`, with an ellipsis.

Can someone please elaborate what the preprocessor **#if ...** does? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Bing's first result for `#if`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-if-hash-elif-hash-else-and-hash-endif-directives-c-cpp?view=msvc-170

Comment: I'm not asking what `#if` does. I'm asking specifically about `#if ...`. I know the ellipses can be used for variadic macros, but I've never seen it used in #if

Comment: A literal `#if ...` is a syntax error. If you found it inside an actual header, it must be nested inside a disabled code block.

Comment: The [C FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/cpp/index.html) has several examples.

Comment: @Azrael: This comment is very important, I edited it into the answer.

Comment: @Neil I'll check that out. Not sure why it didn't show up when I was google searching this problem though.

Comment: @Quentin This specific example is actually from [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-sid) page.

Comment: Are you sure that's not a literal ellipsis?

Comment: That is not meant to be directly usable code. It is just an illustration for documentation purposes. Microsoft is telling you that `SubAuthority` might be either a pointer or an array of some particular size, depending on how the project is compiled, and that you should not depend on the implementation details. (Notice how the documentation also doesn't specify a value for `ANYSIZE_ARRAY`.) As it says at the top of the page, you should not attempt to modify an instance of the struct directly anyway.

Comment: @Azrael it looks like it just redacts the undocumented condition that is in the actual header. Most probably, it checks whether the compiler supports flexible array members.

Comment: @Neil I'm not exactly sure what you mean. I edited the question and posted the MS page that has this exact example on it

Comment: I mean, what @KarlKnechtel said; it's just pseudo-code for what might be there. Admittedly not clear.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Oh okay. I see. I knew it wasn't to be modified. I was just curious about that #if statement. That does make a lot of sense though. If you could word that into an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: This is documentation and the block is pseudo code. Look in `winnt.h` or a `.h` that it includes to find the _real_ code for the struct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation page the code was linked from was not meant to reflect what's actually in the condition of the `#if` directive.  It's only there to show what the options are in terms of what's defined.

The actual winnt.h header on my system (under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include) has the following

```
typedef struct _SID {
   BYTE  Revision;
   BYTE  SubAuthorityCount;
   SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY IdentifierAuthority;
#ifdef MIDL_PASS
   [size_is(SubAuthorityCount)] DWORD SubAuthority[*];
#else // MIDL_PASS
   DWORD SubAuthority[ANYSIZE_ARRAY];
#endif // MIDL_PASS
} SID, *PISID;
```

So there's no actual `...` after `#if`.  It's just there in the documentation for brevity.